# WebView won't allow javascript sites

Tags: android, webview

Is there any way to access a proxy search engine on my webview without getting an error "**Please enable JavaScript on your browser**" at the very bottom of my blank page? I am trying to access YouTube, i have javascript enabled, I even tried changing my user agent string to firefox. but i get the same error.

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebViewClient());

    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);// Enable Cookies
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);// Enable Java Script
    webView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    //webView.loadUrl("https://proxy.zalmos.com/browse.php/wIAIxgVL/ewtldocB/Vgdsa1IE/Mi8_3D/b0/"); // Set Home page
    webView.loadUrl("https://hide.me/en/proxy"); // Set Home page
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    // user agent
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings()
            .setUserAgentString(
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0");
}
```

How is firefox browser able to run it with no issues but not my webView?

PS:

1. I tried `hide.me` proxy. It failed to work on both FireFox(android) and my WebView(android). However, it Worked on firefox for windows.
2. I tried proxy by `zalmos.com`, It works on FireFox(android) without any errors, It won't give any javascript error on my android webview, however, the videos would never start playing on webview.

Answer (score 1):

Include this too in your code: **webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);**

Comment: This allow your webview to work with Document Object Model. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setDomStorageEnabled%28boolean%29/): "Sets whether the DOM storage API is enabled. The default value is false". Cassie, please check as correct my answer if you think it was helful to solve your question. Thank you.

Comment: Cassie, it'a everything ok? Do you get your code running? Need more help? Thanks.